# Android 3D button src padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

[image: button]

On screenshot you can see `src` image is at same position on both states.

I want move image down in pressed state.

**layout**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

**my_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Top 1dp Shadow -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#248349" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- Light bottom color -->
            <item android:top="1dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#2AB564" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#248349"/>
                    <padding
                        android:top="28dp"
                        android:bottom="36dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item> 
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Bottom 3dp Shadow -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#22A863" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- Light top color -->
            <item android:bottom="3dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#2DCC70" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#22A863"/>
                    <padding
                        android:top="36dp"
                        android:bottom="28dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

As you can see, I tried set padding `android:top="36dp" android:bottom="28dp"` and for pressed state `android:top="28dp" android:bottom="36dp"`, but its same as without padding :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to change the image drawable instead of the background. You can create a selector for it, and assign it a custom gravity based on it's pressed state:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Set the `scaletype` of the `ImageButton` to `fitXY`, assign it a minimum width and height, and remove or modify the padding from the background, and it should work.

Comment: great, I added `bitmap` as next `item` to both states, set `android:gravity="center"`, didnt removed `padding` and didnt add `scaleType` (because it has no effect)

Comment: @Shaddow: What I meant was that you can assign this drawable instead to the `src` attribute of the `ImageButton`, not that you should shoehorn all of this in the background of the `View`. That is the only advantage of using `ImageButton` over a normal `View`. It would make your logic much simpler and granular, and remove the need for the padding hack.

Comment: I tried used `scaleType` and `gravity` but it doesnt work for me :/ ... I probably misunderstood your idea or how to implement it.

Comment: @Shaddow: It should work if you add the selector in my answer to a separate drawable file and reference to it in the `ImageButton`'s `android:src` attribute.

Comment: aaaah now I understand, I gonna try it

Comment: nope, when I remove padding, image doesnt move, but I can agree, having src drawable in separated file is better, because I can use it for more buttons

Comment: @Shaddow: Did you set the `scaleType` to `fitXY`? Did you assign a `minHeight` greater that the size of the image? Did you remove the bitmap from the background drawable and add my selector as the `src` attribute? If you did all this, then it should work. If it still doesn't, then update your question with your current layout and drawable XML, and I will take a look at it.

Comment: ok my fault, when I added `android:minHeight="64dp"` its finally moving ... BUT its moving too much (because of `gravity bottom`).

thats why is padding more precise and do correct depth effect.

Comment: @Shaddow: Sure, you can add some padding as needed. My issue was just with using the padding as a hack for positioning the image.

Comment: also its hard determinate height of image, its depends on density (hdpi, mdpi, ldpi, ...) so use height + depth its impossible imho :) It would be great if I could set `minHeight` attribute in drawable xml

Comment: @Shaddow: That's why you should always use [density-independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP) in your layout, which should stay the same size regardless of density. I see that you already use them in your background shape drawables, but you should use them for the stroke width too.